# Correlation - functional relationship small samples size

Tags: regression, correlation, sample-size

I am analysis a dataset made up of a dependant variable (continuous ratio scale data) and more independent variables (continuous data). I am interested in analysing the existing correlation of the dependant variable and each of the independent variable and after (if suitable) running a multiple linear regression in order to describe the relationship between my dependant variable and a significant set of independent variables.
That's the theory.

Translating the above sentence into my practical examples, I am looking at the correlation of an index (continuous ratio scale) with environmental parameters from 9 geographical areas. The problem is that for my dependant variable I have a value for each observation, while for my independent variable(the environmental parameters) I have the mean value from each area (9 areas). 
I have already analysed (one.way ANOVA after validating the model) that the index differs significantly among the different geographical area. 
Now my doubt concerns how to analyse this correlation between my set of variables and after run the multiple linear regression (if suitable).

So I think that I have two options:

1- Analysing the correlation between the mean value of my dependant variable and the independent variable (in this case due to the small sample size(n=9) and the extreme non normality of some of the data) using a Spearman's rank correlation test.

2- Considering the whole dataset (n=190) and use for each observation (from a specific geographical area) of my dependant variable the correspondent mean value for the environmental parameters and run a correlation test (Spearman's as well).

So I am a bit confused on:

- how to arrange and analyse this type of dataset
- if my dataset could be analyse with a multiple regression analysis

(I hope that is clear! =))

Thanks!
Luca